# JSON object with array header

Tags: php, json, mysqli

this question comes from the posting I found here:

[DataTables Multiple Tables from Multiple JSON Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280486/datatables-multiple-tables-from-multiple-json-arrays)

I'd like to know the simplest and best way to generate the JSON below.  I can see the pattern is 'JSON object -> Array Header -> Array -> JSON object' but I do not know how to do this in PHP, from a mySQLi query result.  I imagine having a mySQL table with a 'policies' and 'services' column so the query might look something like:

```
Select name, id, score, type from myTable where type = 'policies' and 
type = 'services'
```

And the result would come back something like:

```
 name        id      score    type
   A          1        0       policies
   B          2        0       services
```

But then how would I take that query and generate this JSON in php?

```
{
 "Policies": [
{
  "name": "A",
  "id": "1",
  "score": "0"
}
],
"Services": [
{
  "name": "B",
  "id": "2",
  "score": "0"
 }
 ]
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I build a correct json from mysqli result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817243/how-can-i-build-a-correct-json-from-mysqli-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating the new empty array.
Then, iterate through the result and add it in the correct sub-array:

```
$new = [];

foreach ($result as $item) {
    // Uppercase the first character
    $type = ucfirst($item['type']);

    if (!isset($new[$type])) {
        // This type doesn't exist in the new array yet, let's create it.
        $new[$type] = [];
    }

    // Add the item
    $new[$type][] = $item;
}

// Output it as json
echo json_encode($new, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

The above code will also work if new types are added to the database.

*PS. The `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` argument is just to make the json string a bit more readable while developing. When everything looks good, you can remove it.*

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry for the delayed response but this appears to work well.